# Should I include other fields in a HABTM table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like an Order object to be comprised of many Product objects, so I set up a HABTM relationship on object.

I'm wondering if it's "correct" (or the Ruby/Rails) way to also include additional data within the HABTM table. For instance, if I need to compute the subtotal and there's a chance the line-item totals might need to be overridden, do I store that as part of the association table, or do I need a LineItem object or something better?

Thanks

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 3) do

create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "order_id", null: false
    t.string   "order_status", default: "new"
    # <snip>
    t.decimal  "pay_total", precision: 8, scale: 2, null: false
end

add_index "orders", ["order_id"], name: "index_orders_on_order_id", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "orders", ["order_status"], name: "index_orders_on_order_status", using: :btree

create_table "orders_products", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "order_id"  # migrated with belongs_to
    t.integer "product_id"  # migrated with belongs_to
    t.decimal "pay_cost",      precision: 8, scale: 2, null: false
    t.decimal "pay_discount",  precision: 8, scale: 2, default: 0.0
    t.decimal "pay_linetotal", precision: 8, scale: 2, null: false
end

add_index "orders_products", ["order_id", "product_id"], name: "index_orders_products_on_order_id_and_product_id", unique: true, using: :btree

create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name",  null: false
    t.decimal "price",  precision: 8, scale: 2,null: false
    t.boolean "active", default: true
end
```

Comment: You should use `has_many :through => `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Join tables (aka HABTM) are purely for joining relationships and Rails (Active Record) ignores any additional fields. However, you can get around this by using a `has_many through` relationship, which would make sense to call "LineItem" instead of "OrdersProducts".

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
end
```

Comment: +1. For clarity - join tables can have additional fields, but it makes absolutely no sense as they are completely ignored. :)

Comment: IIRC Rails 1 used to allow access to the join table's other attributes as attributes on the associated object... it was hideous to debug :-( Use join models for *every* association - HABTM is quick to get up-and-running, but there'll be almost no instance that you'll not want to add other data to the join (sorry for the double negative)